# connection error: Invalid argument at sockets

Tags: c++, sockets

I have this code

```
Server:
//"sock" has already been created with no problem and binding as well

void Connection::bind_connection(int port){
    cout << "Port " << port << endl;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    /* Bind socket to address */
    struct sockaddr *serverptr = ( struct sockaddr *) &server;
    if ( bind ( sock , serverptr , sizeof(server) ) < 0) {
        perror("Binding error"); exit(BE);
    }
    cout << "Server binding completed!" << endl;
}    

struct sockaddr_in client ;
socklen_t clientlen ;
struct sockaddr * clientptr =( struct sockaddr *) &client ;
if ( listen (sock , MAX_CONNECTIONS) < 0) {perror("listening error"); exit(LE);}
cout << "Listening for connections to port " << port << endl;
while (1) {
    /* accept connection */
    if (( newsock = accept ( sock , clientptr , &clientlen ) ) < 0) {
        perror("Accepting error"); cout << "Errno = " << errno << endl; exit(AE);
    }
    //Code
    ....
}
```

and

```
Client:
//struct sockaddr_in server; <--- declared as data member of class "Connection"
//"sock" has already been created with no problem
void Connection::do_connect(){
    struct sockaddr *serverptr = ( struct sockaddr *) &server;
    if ( connect ( sock , serverptr , sizeof (server) ) < 0)
         perror("client connect"); exit(CE);
    cout << "Client connecting to the server" << endl;
}
```

and I get the above message. Most of the code is copied from the lesson slides but modified for my needs. Googling the problem it seems that I give wrong size at the syscall(s). Any idea where exactly the problem is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines always exit:

```
if ( connect ( sock , serverptr , sizeof (server) ) < 0)
     perror("client connect"); exit(CE);
```

You might start to think about using a different indention scheme. Typically one that does not use more then one statement per line.

For the above code a tool like `indent` would have formatted it like this:

```
if (connect (sock, serverptr, sizeof (server)) < 0)
  perror("client connect");
exit(CE);
```

This format makes the programming bug obvious.

Comment: Nice catch, but it doesn't explain the error message stated in the question/subject.

Comment: Literally the error message as shown in this question's title ("connection error: Invalid argument at sockets") would not be issued be the code shown by the OP. @jxh

Comment: The OP did not specify if the error was emitted by the client or server. Given [James M's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24578030/315052), it is safe to say the invalid argument is due to an uninitialized variable. The OP then claimed this did not resolve his issue. You caught a subsequent issue that was only revealed to the OP after the first fix.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize `clientlen`.

```
socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(client);
```

You can catch similar problems in future by running your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Comment: Didn't work. Client exited without any message from do_connect() method.

Answer (score 0):

[As already indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24578030/315052), you do not seem to be initializing your variables properly. You do not show how you initialize your `sockaddr_in` structures, which is likely the culprit. A relatively easy way to specify the address for `bind()` or `connect()` is to use `getaddrinfo()`/`freeaddrinfo()`. [From the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo):

> **Synopsis**
>
> `int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service,
>                  const struct addrinfo *hints,
>                  struct addrinfo **res);`
>       `void freeaddrinfo(struct addrinfo *res);`
>
> **Description**
>
> Given *node* and *service*, which identify an Internet host and a service, `getaddrinfo()` returns one or more addrinfo structures, each of which contains an Internet address that can be specified in a call to `bind(2)` or `connect(2)`. ...
>
> The `freeaddrinfo()`function frees the memory that was allocated for the dynamically allocated linked list *res*.

As a simple example, here is a function that can connect to a server specified by a string that has the format `<servername>:<port>`:

```
int connect_tcp (std::string hostspec) {
    struct addrinfo hints = { .ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV };
    struct addrinfo *res = 0;
    std::istringstream ss(hostspec);
    std::string node, service;
    int sock = -1;
    std::getline(ss, node, ':');
    std::getline(ss, service, ':');
    getaddrinfo(node.c_str(), service.c_str(), &hints, &res);
    for (struct addrinfo *rp = res; rp != 0; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        if (rp->ai_socktype != SOCK_STREAM) continue;
        int sock = socket(rp->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sock == -1) continue;
        if (connect(sock, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
            break;
        close(sock);
        sock = -1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    if (sock == -1) errno = EHOSTDOWN;
    return sock;
}
```